# Notificación de AJAX con animated

Tags: css, ajax

estoy intentando poner en un AJAX que cuando se muestre el `success` salga un div y al poco se vuelva a esconder y lo estoy intentando hacer con animations, lo estoy haciendo asi pero sin resultado.

```
      success: function(){
         $("#smsTodasVistas").html("<div class=\"aceptada animate bounceInDown\"> Notificación eliminada...</div>");
         $('.aceptada').show({ animated: "bounceInUp" }, "slow");
         $('.aceptada').hide({ animated: "bounceInUp" }, "slow");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

No lo probé, pero el problema podría radicar en el que no le das tiempo para poder mostrarte la información.

Una solución posible seria el de esperar un poco de tiempo y luego esconderlo. Para tal acción puedes utilizar `setTimeout` el cual tiene dos parámetros, el primero es una **función** en donde realizas las acciones que desees y el segundo un entero que indica el tiempo en mili segundos.

Solucion:

```
success: function(){
     $("#smsTodasVistas").html("<div class=\"aceptada animate bounceInDown\"> Notificación eliminada...</div>");
     $('.aceptada').show({ animated: "bounceInUp" }, "slow");
     setTimeout(function(){
                $('.aceptada').hide({ animated: "bounceInUp" }, "slow");
                },3000);
}
```

Su función seria esperar 3 segundos antes de desaparecerlo.

**Edicion**

De acuerdo a los comentarios el `hide`, no funciona, no tengo claro el porque, pero podrias intentar con:

```
$('.aceptada').hide( 2000, function() {
  $( this ).remove();
});
```

Comment: Hola @Sassain ahora si da tiempo a que se ejecute, pero parece que solo hace el `hide` el animated no

Comment: Hace los mismo @Shassain por eso te comentaba que no hace la para te animated

Comment: Quizas no me explique bien, el `hide` si que funciona, lo que no hace es el `animated: "bounceInUp` @Shassain

Comment: mmm ahí no sabria decirte, al ponerlo en el `div` normalmente ya lo tendría que hacer no? tengo animations.css

Comment: No te preocupes sigo investigando por que no funciona, si lo resuelvo lo publico, gracias por tu tiempo @Shassain